# What does `^` mean in tensorflow PB file?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I wrote following code and executed, then a PB file called `test.pb` generated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,2,3,4], name="x")
mu, sigma = tf.nn.moments(x, [0,1,2])
in_data = np.array([i for i in range(24)]).reshape([1,2,3,4])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print sess.run([mu, sigma], feed_dict={x: in_data})

tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, "./", "test.pb")
```

In `test.pb`, there's a node:

```
node {
  name: "moments/normalize/divisor"
  op: "Reciprocal"
  input: "moments/sufficient_statistics/Const"
  input: "^moments/sufficient_statistics/mean_ss"
  input: "^moments/sufficient_statistics/var_ss"
  attr {
    key: "T" 
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }   
  }
}
```

My question is that what the punctuation `^` mean in `^moments/sufficient_statistics/mean_ss` and `^moments/sufficient_statistics/var_ss`?

Comment: Control dependencies

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov The actual node name is `moments/sufficient_statistics/mean_ss` and `moments/sufficient_statistics/var_ss`, why there is a `^`?

Comment: it means it's a control dependency